# Can I open object URL in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have used Blob and URL.createObjectURL() to get an "object URL" (blob:) to some binary PDF data.

In FireFox and Chrome, if I include an `<A/>` link HTML element, with its `href` programmatically set to the object URL, that link is clickable and causes the PDF to be shown.

In IE10, I get the object URL OK. The link HTML element shows OK and has a blob: target. But clicking on it does not result in the PDF being shown. Instead, I get a blank window and the IE icon spinning forever.

Yet, even in IE10, right-click save-target-as on the link *does* save a PDF file containing the correct data. This file can be opened successfully outside of the browser.

Anyone know why IE isn't showing me the PDF file? Any suggestions how I can cause it to do so? Alternatively, any suggestions for persuading it only to offer to save the link, rather than trying and failing to open it.

Here is a page and script to reproduce the issue: -

```
<a href="" target="_blank" id="theLink">Click this link</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var TEST_PDF_DATA = "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";
    var byteCharacters = atob(TEST_PDF_DATA);

    var charCodeFromCharacter = function(c) { return c.charCodeAt(0); }
    var byteArrays = [];
    for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += 1000)
    {
        var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + 1000);
        var byteNumbers = Array.prototype.map.call(slice, charCodeFromCharacter);
        byteArrays.push(new Uint8Array(byteNumbers));
    }

    var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: "application/pdf" });
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    document.getElementById("theLink").href = url;
    document.getElementById("theLink").innerHTML = url;
</script>
```

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** and include valid code to reproduce it. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

Comment: IE cannot natively render a PDF. What PDF plugin are you trying to use? It's possible that some PDF viewers aren't able to properly bind to a blob-originating document.

Comment: What's the point of an "on hold" system, and telling me what I need to do to fix my question, if no-one does anything about it when I fix it in that way?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following url

https://superuser.com/questions/560647/ie10-unexpectedly-sends-a-head-request-for-pdf-what-has-changed

Looks like IE10 is sending a head request

Comment: Really? I can understand that this would affect an http: URL, but a blob:?

Comment: Link only answers aren't advise on SO, you should extract the relevant content and reference it in you answer. This way if the link dies the answer is still worth something.

Answer (score 0):

You should open the url first as user action then populate pdf

Check this one:

[how to bypass pop-up blocker in angular 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54251743/how-to-bypass-pop-up-blocker-in-angular-6)