# how to bypass pop-up blocker in angular 6?

Tags: angular, html, typescript

i want to show pdf on clicking preview button but pdf is blocked while opening in a new tab .. So , I want to by pass pop-up blocker property of browsers

```
     getPdf(projectId) {
this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + "/poject/getPdf/" + projectId + '/' + this.userDataSession.userDetailsId + '/' + 8 + '/' + this.authService.getUserToken(), { responseType: 'blob' })
  .subscribe((blob: Blob) => {
    let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    let link = document.createElement("a");
    if (link.download !== undefined) {
      let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      let win = window.open(url, '_blank');
      win.focus();
      link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
    }

  });
```

}

This is how i am accessing pdf from server and want to show in a new window but browser is blocking the pop up

Comment: If it were so easy to bypass, it wouldn't be there to begin with.

Comment: then how to overcome this problem.I want to show a pdf on clicking preview button

Comment: Just browse to the PDF, the browser will handle it however it's supposed to. Link to http://example.com/file.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will help you to open attachment(file in new window) without pop up blocker

```
getPdf(projectId) {
  let newWindow = window.open();//OPEN WINDOW FIRST ON SUBMIT THEN POPULATE PDF
  this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + "/PROJECT/getPdf/" + projectId + '/' + this.userDataSession.userDetailsId + '/' + 9 + '/' + this.authService.getUserToken(), { responseType: 'blob' })
    .subscribe((blob: Blob) => {
      let file = new Blob([blob], { type: 'application/pdf' });
      let url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      this.router.navigate([url]);
      newWindow.location.href = url;//POPULATING PDF 
    });
}
```